# Noob-Ready Cython Tutorials

Tags: python, c, cython

I know a bunch of scripting languages, (python, ruby, lua, php) but I don't know any compiled languages like C/C++ , I wanted to try and speed up some python code using cython, which is essentially a python -> C compiler, aimed at creating C extensions for python. Basically you code in a stricter version of python which compiles into C -> native code.

here's the problem, I don't know C, yet the cython documentation is aimed at people who obviously already know C (nothing is explained, only presented), and is of no help  to me, I need to know if there are any good cython tutorials aimed at python programmers, or if I'm gonna have to learn C before I learn Cython.

bear in mind I'm a competent python programmer, i would much rather learn cython from the perspective of the language I'm already good at, rather than learn a whole new language in order to learn cython.

1) PLEASE don't recommend psyco

edit: ANY information that will help understand the oficial cython docs is useful information

Comment: i just want to  learn cython from a python users perspective, ie: with all the "C stuff" explained, rather than just presented. thanks.

Comment: So you want to use C without learning C?  Is that what you're asking?  Are you asking for a "royal road" to C that doesn't involve learning anything?  What programming problem do you have?  Is that you need to read C or need to write C?  I don't get the question.

Comment: @spearfire, I have the same question and I got the same answer. and... I still don't wanna see the K&R book. after learning Python, it's pain to read this(or whatever C) book.

Comment: C sucks for all but embeded development and Operating Systems (which support nothing better). C++ is a great language to learn. But it requires much learning about Computer architecture.

Comment: Maybe too late but I found this reference " Cython - A guide for Python programmers" from Kurt W. Smith

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Learn C!  (Sorry -- irresistible.)

Seriously, though, it seems like you mostly need to know about [C variable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations) (C types, if you will) in order to use `cdef` effectively.

Later on, if you do decide to bite the bullet and learn C properly, treat yourself to a copy of [Kernighan and Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)), or K & R, available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).

Comment: ths is how it has to be i guess, i just wanted to know if there was  hope. thanks anyway. p.s python is useless for "real world" stuff

Comment: I don't think python is useless for real world stuff.  Off the top of my head, I know Pixar uses it for a core piece of their operation.

Comment: Python is generally not great for things that are really performance dependent. But there are plenty of programs where speed is really not that important, or where it is important but where other things are the bottle neck. Such as with websites where http requests and the like are the bottle neck and the python runs in a small fraction of a second. Cython / C dependencies can allow Python to still work for performance dependent programs, but vanilla Python will really struggle.

Answer (score 18):

`cython` is good at two different things

1. Interfacing with C language libraries
2. Speeding up Python code

It probably gets more exposure from 1. hence the emphasis on the tutorial materials you've found towards C stuff.  It sounds like you want to use it like 2. though.

From my experience with `cython` you can just try compiling your python programs and see if it works.  It will get a bit faster (maybe).  To get a lot faster you need to selectively turn python types into C types.  This starts to bring out the power of cython.

If you look at the [official tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/docs/tutorial.html) you need to study where they've used the `cdef` keyword.

So to recap

1. Make your existing python program compile with cython with as few changes as possible
2. Declare some variables as `cdef` and make it work again
3. If not fast enough go to step 2.

I'm sorry that isn't a pointer to a tutorial, but it should give you a direction to go in!

Comment: thanks a lot, i also wondered if maybe there's a C tutorial on the basic structure of C that will help understand the offical cython docs better

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this: http://www.perrygeo.net/wordpress/?p=116 seems like a pretty good overview. You could also have a look at the source in pyzmq and gevent - they use Cython for their core code.

Ben

Comment: Your link is dead. Do you remember if it pointed to [this article](http://www.perrygeo.com/a-quick-cython-introduction.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Cython does support concurrency (you can use native POSIX threads with c, that can be compiled in extent ion module)  , you just need to be careful enough to not to modify any python objects when GIL is released and keep in mind the interpreter itself is not thread safe. You can also use multiprocessing with python to use more cores for parallelism which can in turn use your compiled cython extensions to speed up even more. But all in all you definitely have to know  c programming model , static types etc

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot of very useful things with Cython if you can answer the following C quiz...

(1) What is a double? What is an int?

(2) What does the word "compile" mean?

(3) What is a header (.h) file?

To answer these questions you don't need to read a whole C book! ...maybe chapter 1.

Once you can pass that quiz, try again with the tutorial.

What I usually do is start with pure python code, and add Cython elements bit by bit. In that situation, you can learn the Cython features bit by bit. For example I don't understand C strings, because so far I have not tried to cythonize code that involves strings. When I do, I will first look up how strings work in C, and then second look up how strings work in Cython.

Again, once you've gotten started with Cython, you will now and then run into some complication that requires learning slightly more C. And of course the more C you know, the more dextrous you will be with taking full advantage of Cython, not to mention troubleshooting if something goes wrong. But that shouldn't make you reluctant to start!

Answer (score 0):

About all the C that you really need to know is:

1. C types are much faster than Python types (adding to C ints or doubles can be done in a single clock cycle) but less safe (they are not arbitrarily sized and may silently overflow).
2. C function (`cdef`) calls are much faster than Python (`def`) function calls (but are less flexible).

This will get you most of the way there. If you want to eke out that last 10-20% speedup for most applications, there's no getting around knowing C, and how modern processes work (pointers, cache, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Cython does not support threads well at all. It holds the GIL (Global Intrepreter Lock) the entire time! This makes your code thread-safe by (virtually) disabling concurrent execution. So I wouldn't use it for general purpose development.

Comment: That's not true. Under certain conditions, you could add `nogil` to the function signature or blocks of code.